# Nested sequence of compact connected sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose that $K_1 \supset K_2 \supset K_3 \supset \dots $
is a nested sequence of compact connected subsets of $S^2$ such that
$\pi_1(K_j)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ for all $j$.
Prove or provide a counterexample for each of the following statements:

a. $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty K_j$ is connected.

b. $\pi_1(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty K_j)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint for part b: Use the Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: @DanRust How do you use Banach fixed point theorem here, can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Anubhav As in the answer below, one finds a contracting map from a space $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ to itself. The intersection of the nested sets is then the unique fixed point and so has trivial fundamental group.

Answer (score 1):

a. is true.

suppose, $K_\infty:=\bigcap K_i$ is not connected; then there exist two open sets $U_1,U_2$ such that $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$, $K_\infty\subset U_1\cup U_2$ and $U_j\cap K_\infty\ne\emptyset$.

then $L_i:=K_i\cap(S^2\setminus U_1\cup U_2)\ne\emptyset$, because $K_i\cap U_j$ is nonempty and $K_i$ are connected; also, $L_i$ are closed in $S^2$. so we have a contradiction: $\emptyset\ne\bigcap L_i\cap(U_1\cup U_2)$.

b. is false.

just take a collection of discs $\{D_i\}$ with radius of $D_i$ equals to $1/2^{i}$, such that $D_{i+1}\subset D_i$, and then let $K_i=D_i\setminus(\text{small open disc, disjoint with }D_{i+1})$.

$\pi_1(K_\infty)=0$ because all the maps $\pi_1(K_i)\to \pi_1(K_{i-1})$ are zero, so the limit of the diagram will be zero too. the picture like that:

[image]

PS: if in a. you need to *path connectness*, of course the answer will be false too, find an example yourself

Comment: $\pi_1(K_3)\neq \mathbb Z$ , or $K_3$ does not contained in $K_2$ (if I got your part b right)

Comment: @Anubhav i edit my answer, maybe the picture will be more understandable..

Comment: I got the pic, I read it wrong initially.